# Numpy Mask using np.count_nonzero() for individual rows

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to create a numpy mask to individual rows in a numpy array without using a for loop?

Example: If row has more than zero nonzero values, apply a True mask

Given input: `array = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,0]]`

Expected output: `mask = [False,True,True,False]`

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,0]])

mask = []

num_nonzero_specified = 0

a_len = len(a[0])
for b in a:
    if np.count_nonzero(b) > num_nonzero_specified:
        mask.append([True] * a_len)
    else:
        mask.append([False] * a_len)

masked_array = np.ma.MaskedArray(a,mask=mask)
```

My goal is to know whether there was a faster implementation of the above code, which allowed me to use multiple different values for the number of nonzero elements.

Answer (score 2):

This could be made by numpy itself. But you have to think a little.

First you need to write out your condition and observe what will you get. For example:

```
>>> print(array>0)
[[False False]
 [False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False False]]
```

Then you should find a method which will aggregate your results. For this task the aggregate method **any** is the best approach. It works as well as builtin's **any** works, but you can explicitly specify the axis you want to aggregate. For example:

```
>>> print((array>0).any(axis=1))
[False  True  True False]
```

---

So the answer to you question is: `mask = (array>0).any(axis=1)`